# How to create a function that cannot be executed by a constructor?

Tags: java

Say I have function `x` which is a function in an abstract class. `x` adds itself to a private arraylist if it does not already contain it. I want to make a function that cannot be executed inside the constructor so that 'x' cannot be added to the arraylist if the constructor errors, and can only be called after the constructor(s) has finished. The gist of my situation is that I want the set to be private so only the class A can access it, nothing should ever be removed from the list if it is added, the addToArray function should only ever need to happen once and should never happen from the constructor. The constructor would only matter if it is a subclass' constructor.

```java
public abstract class A {
    public A () {
        //do stuff :)
    }
    public abstract void doStuff();
    public final void addToArray() {
        if(isCalledFromConstructor/*HELP ME HERE*/)
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot execute addToArray function from a constructor");
        if(!AS.contains(this))AS.add(this);
    }
    private static final java.util.Set<A> AS = new java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet<A>();
    public static final class B extends A {
        public B(){
            addToArray();//THROW AN ERROR HERE
        }
        @Override
        public void doStuff(){
            System.out.println("Doing stuff");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really don't see the purpose of this.  Just create the class and then use an `addMethod` to add values to the List.

Comment: @WJS If the addToArray function is executed from the constructor, then the constructor errors, the object is still accessible even though it is broken. This could cause some pretty bad null pointer exceptions. That's the least of it.

Comment: Then don't put the addMethod in the constructor.  If you're worried about NPE's then use something like `Objects.requiresNonNull()` or something similar.  If someone does something to throw an NPE, etc,  they need to debug their program.  You can't really protect someone from writing bad code.

Comment: Why are you saving references of its instances in a private static list? This looks like an observer pattern but using static list.

Comment: Why not just accept that subclass implementers have to write code that works correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With more context on what you’re trying to accomplish, I might be able to give a better suggestion on achieving your ultimate goal. That said, if you are absolutely set on doing what you are asking, one way is to call

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```

from within `addToArray` and examine the contents of the stack trace to see if you’re currently inside of a constructor.

In particular this

```
  boolean isCalledFromConstructor() {
    StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    for (StackTraceElement stackTraceElement : stackTrace) {
      String methodName = stackTraceElement.getMethodName();
      if (methodName.equals("<init>")) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

should do it for you, although it's not my favorite bit of code :)

As other people have commented, doing this may be a sign of a design oversight. Please give more details on the big picture goal if you can.

Comment: what if I override the method that that is in?

Comment: @WJS good point - the 'addToArray' method should be made `final` if OP is going to depend on the above. Ultimately, whatever OP is trying to do would best be accomplished with another approach, but without more details I can't advise.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a private variable like `boolean isInitialized` and set this to true in constructor. In the add method check if this value is `false` and throw error.

If your environment allows it you could use `@PostConstruct` method annotation to add it to your list safely.

But i also recommend to check your code design. You are adding an instance to a private static list that is not thread safe.

Comment: I considered that for a moment.  But what if someone overrides the method (or must it be declared final)?  Or subclasses and adds a new constructor.  What about race conditions in a mutli-threaded environment.  Too many problems to tackle, imo.

Comment: I understand. I plan to replace this implementation with a ConcurrentMap.

Comment: @WJS i agree but the whole original code will tackle a lot of problems anyway. I just showed one solution in case the method will be final.